# Using QGIS on network with heavy firewalls?

Tags: qgis

I'm having a problem keeping QGIS 2.18 running on a government network computer with heavy firewalls.

The software downloaded with no apparent issues, however I do not have access to any web layers, web tools, or plugins. And the software is really unstable.

I used a local raster and pulled a local .txt table and it couldn't handle this without timing out and forcing a shut down.

Could this be an Internet problem even though this app runs from my local drive?

Comment: you can set your proxy in the Settings->Options->Network tab to handle your firewall

Comment: Sadly, I could not add Qgis to the allowed programs, and I do not have permissions to view the firewall log. BUT thank you for the help. I will work on this with the IT department.